# Como permitir que outra aplicação inicie a minha?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8-1

Já pesquisei um bocado, mas não sei como fazer para estar na lista de aplicações que podem abrir um certo tipo de arquivo, por exemplo, uma foto. O que eu quero é como se o whatsapp (ou qualquer outra aplicação) colocasse a minha app na lista de aplicações que podem retornar uma informação (como o caso da foto) para essa aplicação.
Existe alguma forma? Se sim, como? E como eu faria para retornar a informação para a aplicação que fez o pedido para a minha implementação?

Comment: Você já deu uma olhada em Auto Launch Apps? Acredito que isso seja o que você está procurando. [Auto-launching apps using file and URI associations for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) Abraços.

Answer (score -3):

Não tenho certeza se entendi sua perguta mas

O que você está procurando é a capacidade de registrar sua aplicação como uma manipuladora (handler) para um determinado tipo de arquivo, permitindo que ela seja uma opção quando o usuário tenta abrir esse tipo de arquivo de outra aplicação.

A capacidade de manipular tipos específicos de arquivos geralmente envolve a definição de intenções (intents) no Android ou extensões de tipo de arquivo no iOS. Vou fornecer uma breve visão geral de como isso pode ser feito em ambas as plataformas.

Android:
Para registrar sua aplicação como manipuladora de um determinado tipo de arquivo no Android, você precisa editar o arquivo AndroidManifest.xml. Abaixo está um exemplo de como você pode adicionar uma intenção (intent) para manipular imagens:

xml

```
<activity>
    ...
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Essa configuração indica que sua atividade pode lidar com a visualização de dados do tipo "image/*". Você precisará personalizar isso conforme necessário para o seu caso específico.

**Retornando informações para a aplicação solicitante:**

Para retornar informações para a aplicação solicitante, geralmente você usa mecanismos como intents no Android. Quando sua aplicação é iniciada, você verifica os dados recebidos (por exemplo, o caminho do arquivo) e responde conforme necessário.

Comment: A pergunta não nem sobre Android e nem sobre IOS, a pergunta é especifica sobre a plataforma Windows Phone 8. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/jj206987(v=vs.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN